# Ionic 2 sqlstorage get function return array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic2, local-storage, sqlstorage

im wondering if there is a way to get the reponse of that following code in an array?

```
this.storage.get('name').then((value) => { return JSON.parse(value); });
```

im only getting it in a reponse type and can only see my data in zone_symbol__value but i want it in an array how to do it?
[image]

here is my code

```
this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM PharmacieGarde where groupe = ?", [this.GRP])
  .then((data) => {
    this.gardelist = [];
    if(data.rows.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
        this.gardelist.push({
          nom: data.rows.item(i).nom,
          quartier: data.rows.item(i).quartier
        });
      }
      this.storage.set('name111', JSON.stringify(this.gardelist));
      this.loader1.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

the data reading function

```
console.log("ghghgh", this.storage.get('name111').then((value) => {
  return JSON.parse(value);
}));
```

My code is working but instead of a promise type response , i just want the response in an array

Comment: Do you mean that `zone_symbol__value` is the name of an array property  on the deserialized object?. If it is, write `this.storage.get('name').then(value => JSON.parse(value).zone_symbol__value);` and you are done. If this happens frequently, create a service that wraps this process.

Comment: yes i think so but i want it in an array of my choice not in a reponse type. i posted the capture of what im getting

Comment: what do you mean an array of your choice? Do you mean an object like `{ name: [1, 2, 3] }`?

Comment: exactly. now im trying your solution

Comment: `this.storage.get('name').then(value => ({name: JSON.parse(value).zone_symbol__value}));` will do that but I think you need to take a step back and focus on basic JavaScript knowledge before diving into frameworks as complex as Angular 2.

Comment: Also, it looks you are storing a promise instead of its result in the first place, that is probably why it has that shape. You  probably have some code like `this.storage.set('name', value)` that should be rewritten `value.then(v => { this.storage.set('name', v);})` on the value producing end.

Comment: i tried your solution but im still getting the same type. its just the array name that changed. what i mean i want to have my data in an array named myarray for example

Comment: An array on what? There are several things going on here. Likely the code that stores the value is not correct.

Comment: in this type : name111
:
Array[21]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object

Comment: That is not a type, FYI, that is just what the value looks like in the console. Please show how you want to use the array. Also post the code that stores the array

Comment: not that type : t
__zone_symbol__state
:
true
__zone_symbol__value
:
Object
name111
:
Array[21]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
10
:
Object
11
:
Object
12
:
Object
13
:
Object

Comment: i got the code from this link https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage

Comment: That is fine, but I need to see how you use it. You are not using it correctly. Please add code to your question. Specifically, the function that saves the data and the function that reads the data.

Comment: function for saving the data : this.storage.set('name111', JSON.stringify(this.gardelist)); this.gardelist is an array.

Comment: Please add that your question, not the comment. Also post the class and an example of its use.

Comment: function that reads the data : this.storage.get('name111').then(value => ({name111: JSON.parse(value).zone_symbol_value}))

Comment: Edit your question. Include the class containing the call. Please understand there is nothing that can be explained further without more context. I do not think that `this.gradelist` is an array.

Comment: Just use a local `const gradeList = []` and assign to `this.gradeList` later. This will help identify the issue as it is not a promise as you say.

Comment: Thank you Aluan Haddad for your help, i wanted to have an array on storage.get function but i thnik it can only give the king of response i posted. you've helped me a lot thanks but you can post me a sample code of what im trying to get it is welcomed sorry for my english i speak french

Comment: The problem is that I cannot write anything to help without seeing more of your use case. What I see is that you load some data, then you store it immediately. This looks like it should work but it doesn't make much sense. This suggests you are leaving out important details. Also, make sure you read the documentation which says to call `storage.ready()` before use. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage#usage